# Handling exceptions of overridden methods from the base class in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, exception

I am coding a program (which is actually a library) which is supposed to do some kind of processing on a given dataset. The program has a plugin mechanism. Each plugin follows a different processing strategy on the data. The idea is that the user can create his own processing strategy in a plugin and he wont have to touch the code of the program. The software is a server-based application and it will never terminate. The problem is the following: What if the user provides his own plugin but his code throws an unhandled exception? This will make the application to crash and the server will go offline. Given the fact that the plugins always create an object that derives from the class visible to both the library and the plugin the obvious solution would be:

```
class AbstractSolver
{
public:
    void solve(void)
    {
        try {
        this->solve_impl();
        } catch (...) {
            std::cout << "got exception" << std::endl;
        }
    }
private:
    virtual void solve_impl(void) = 0;
};

// This is the class of the plugin
class MySolver : public AbstractSolver
{
private:
    void solve_impl(void)
    {
        throw std::exception();
    }
}
```

Although this is going to work, I don't want to write try and catch statements for every single public method of the AbstractSolver class. Also, I want to avoid macros and I would prefer a c++ 11 solution. I was thinking of introducing an ExceptionGuard class that would take as parameter of its constructor the solve_impl method and will perform the try/catch in there. I tried to do that using std::function to pass the method but I kinda failed. Do you have to suggest a more elegant solution? Thank you.

Comment: You should either [1] declare the virtual function as `noexcept` in the base class to prevent the derived class from throwing an exception, or [2] define the set of exceptions that may be thrown then catch just those (and handle them using [an exception translator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/01/16/exception-boundaries.aspx).  Don't catch `...`; you have no idea what might have gone wrong or what the state of the system is.

Comment: I am not quite sure what noexcept does but nothing will change if I declare the virtual function as noexcept. The exception is still thrown.

Comment: Declaring the `virtual` function hook `noexcept` doesn't really solve the OP's problem.  Without the `try`/`catch` block, the application crashes because the plugin threw an unhandled exception.  With `noexcept`, the application crashes because the plugin violated the exception specification and the runtime calls `terminate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What if the user provides his own plugin but his code throws an unhanded exception? This will make the application to crash and the server will go offline.

If the user-provided plugin throws an exception that is not allowed by the plugin specification, then that is a logic error in the user-provided plugin.  The correct thing to do when a logic error is detected is to stop execution immediately and terminate the process (possibly after a final attempt to log the failure or to notify some other component in the system of the impending termination).

You might as well ask "what if the user provides his own plugin but his code performs indirection through null pointer?" or "what if the user provides his own plugin but his code goes  into an infinite loop or causes a deadlock and never returns?"  A logic error is a logic error:  when you detect it, you have no way of knowing what the state of the process is and whether it is safe to continue execution.

If plugins must not throw exceptions, declare the virtual function as `noexcept` in the base class.  This will require all overrides in derived classes to be `noexcept` as well.  If an override fails to handle an exception and that exception leaks across the `noexcept` boundary, `std::terminate()` will be called, terminating execution.  If you need to be able to restart the service on termination, consider using a watchdog process that monitors the service.

For the more general problem of handling exceptions at an exception boundary, consider using an exception translator and wrapping the code that may throw into a lambda expression.  I wrote a detailed article about this:  ["Exception Boundaries."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/01/16/exception-boundaries.aspx)